# LG Revolution and Android Development

Tags: android, windows-7, 64-bit, adb

I am trying to use my Revolution with my Windows x64 machine

I got the LG Revolution the day it came out and have been very happy with it so far except for this problem.  Whenever I connect the device to the computer (doesn't matter which mode), I get random error messages about Device not recognized.  I have used different cables/OS/computers.  I have the LG USB drivers loaded.

I ran adb devices in Command Line and i get no connected devices. it's as if the OS doesn't see the phone.

i downloaded the drivers from [LG Revolution Drivers](http://s3.amazonaws.com/lgforum.com/resources/assets/696/original/LG%20VZW_United_WHQL_v1.2.0.zip?1307481415)

Please help. Any advice or steps needed to fix would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After hours and hours of trying to figure it out; I realize that I have to place the phone into "Internet Connection" mode. (Which is counter intuitive).

Comment: Thanks so much, I was really going crazy with this one. So counter-intuitive.